# How can I make a customized font based on DeJaVu?

Tags: fonts, fontforge

My favorite font is `DeJaVu Sans Mono` whose style is book. I often cannot tell `P` (uppercase) from `p` (lowercase), so I want to make a customized font based on `DeJaVu Sans Mono-book`.
Note that  `0` in `DeJaVu Sans Mono-book` contains a solid dot.

[image: zero in DeJaVu Sans Mono--book]

I want to create a `P` (p in uppercase) in my format like below.

[image]

With fontforge, how do I create my font based on DeJaVu and save the revised font as `myfont.ttf`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The process is pretty easy.

1. Open the `DejaVu Sans Mono` using *FontForge*
2. Double click on the glyph you want to change
3. Use "*Ellipse*" tool to create the small dot inside the glyph.
   You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + *drag* to create a circle.

[image: FontForge Ellipse tool]

4. Use "*Pointer*" tool to select the circle and position it at the middle of the ellipse of the glyph:

[image: FontForge Pointer tool]

5. Change font name. In order for the changed glyphs to take effect on the new generated, **you have to apply a new font name**. Go to menu *Element* ➜ *Font Info* and change "Fontname", "Family Name" and "Name For Humans" to a different name:

[image: FontForge Font Info]

6. Go to menu *File* ➜ *Generate Fonts*, select `TrueType` the path and the filename of the new font:

[image: FontForge Generate Fonts]

And you now have your newly created font with the glyphs changed with the dots inside `P`, `p` and every other glyph you may apply a dot ellipse:

[image: FontExpert preview]